# VSTS "Publish Artifact" powershell script

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm currently using the "Publish Artifact" task as part of my VSTS build, this all works fine.

I would now like to do a custom version of the this task as I would like to selectively choose which artifacts are published. Can someone tell me if there is a powershell script somewhere that does what the "Publish Artifact" task actually does? Such that I could modify and use the script within my build definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to modify anything to achieve what you want.

- You can manipulate the file system to your heart's content via PowerShell scripts in order to arrange the folder you want to publish how you'd like
- You can use multiple *Publish Artifacts* tasks to publish different sets of artifacts
- You can control the conditions under which a given task runs with [conditional rules](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the source code to custom the task: [PublishBuildArtifacts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PublishBuildArtifacts).

It uses task.uploadfile command to upload files to container, which could call from PowerShell, for example: `Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadfile]c:\additionalfile.log"`

[Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

On the other hand, as Daniel said that you should be no need to custom it.