# Publish PipelineArtifact from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to [Publish Pipeline Artefact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) from a PowerShell script?

I would like to avoid creating an extra pipeline task for publishing files.

**Instead of:**

```
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'publish azuredeploy.parameters.json'
        inputs:
          targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/work
          artifactName: azuredeploy parameters
```

**I'd rather prefer to do something like that:**

```
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'replace ARM parameters'
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          pwsh: true
          script: |
              # input
              $manifest = ReadObject "work/manifest.json"

              # process
              ReplaceArmTemplateParameters $manifest.modules

              # output
              PublishPipelineArtefact -targetPath "work/manifest.json" -artefactName "azuredeploy-parameters"
```

Maybe the build agent provides an API that can be used within a `PowerShell@2` Task, something like: `Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PublishPipelineArtifactTask::PipelineArtifactTaskPluginBaseV1`

Any ideas?

(ps: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202005/vsts-publish-artifact-powershell-script) question seems to be a bit outdated)

Comment: *I would like to avoid creating an extra pipeline task for publishing files.* Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it will be a part of the script you can use the [Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

1. `##vso[artifact.associate]artifact location` - Create an artifact link, artifact location is required to be a file container path, VC path or UNC share path.
2. `##vso[artifact.upload]local file path` - Upload local file into a file container folder, create artifact if artifactname provided.

You use it with `Write-Host`, for example:

```
Write-Host "##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder=test;artifactname=drop;]c:\test.zip"
```

Another option is not to use `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task, there is more [easier and shorter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publishing-artifacts):

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```